# Uploading to multiple buckets throughout the project

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

we are developing a firebase powered angular app. We are trying to use the [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) package for storage interaction (mainly for uploading files).

[It looks like](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md) the only way to configure a specific bucket, as the storage target for the AngularFireStorage object, is through injecting it in the  module that uses the storage service.

This is highly constraining since our backend model depends on different files being stored on different buckets, with respect to their types.

does anybody know of a way to access MULTIPLE buckets in one angular app?

Thanks in advance! this will help us a lot.